# Has anyone had old fullcalendar events vanish?

Tags: javascript

Has anyone ever had old fullcalendar events in Drupal 7 appear to delete themselves? On our site we had a bunch of ones that had been updated in late 2014 and are no longer showing as there, either published or unpublished. I had been cleaning out older ones from 2012 & 2013, however, when I left work last week, the ones from 2014 on were still there. Today, they're gone. No one else was deleting events. Is there anything about recurring events that I could have messed up and caused others to be deleted?